# two layout problems (white background and messed up layout in IE9)

Tags: html, css

I have two problems with my website : http://test2.tamarawobben.nl

Problem 1 : In IE9 the header is placed well but the text area is at the wrong place.

Problem 2 : An area around the header stays white but it supposes to be shown the background.

Anyone a tip how to solve these two anoying problems?

Roelof

Edit 1 : Sorry, the wrong url. I will change it now.

Comment: WEll for me it looks same on chrome and IE9, and it looks good. I dont see any white background, and i also dont think text area is in wrong place, at least doesnt seem so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the first problem, it's is not very clear what it is that it's not ok.

I guess the search field is supposed stick to the top of the page. Right now it looks like the body has a margin-top or a padding.
Actually looking at the markup, there is a textnode right after the body which adds the space at the top:

[image]

Remove it and the "sort-of" margin will go away.

---

Concerning the white background, you are using a [GIF](http://test2.tamarawobben.nl/images/outer-back.gif) that has a white background! It won't magically dissapear. You have several choices:

- change the image format to PNG and set the white to transparent
- have separate images for the different parts (the search and the top of main content zone)
- set the white color to transparent in the GIF (really not a good solution)

---

I also noticed that your `<meta>`, `<title>`... tags should be in the HEAD and not in the BODY !

Comment: Oke, PNG is supported by most of the browsers  ?

Comment: IE6 does not support it, but you don't want to support IE6 anyway. Check this [support table](http://caniuse.com/png-alpha).